# Subtracting totals using the same table with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a payment table in a SQL Server 2008 database, this holds both payment amounts and credit amounts, credits are identified by the field `txt_pay_type` which would be equal to 'credit'.

I am trying to output some reports, one being total revenue per website.

I am using this select statement to get the sum and average values per website, how can i get it to take away the credit amounts.

So the final webTotal is less and credits.

I.e do a sum of all the payments which are not credits (like below), do a sum for all the payments which are credits and take one from the other. Or i am better to do this on the page with cold fusion?

E.g Website 1 Total of 5000 in payments, 1000 in credits. Results would be;

```
Website    Total Revenue  Average Sale   
Website 1  4000           200.00


SELECT 
  txt_web_name,
  SUM(mon_pay_amount) AS webTotal,
  AVG(mon_pay_amount) AS webAvg
FROM
  tbl_payment
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)
  INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_websites ON (uid_order_webid = uid_websites)
WHERE
  dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes">
  AND txt_pay_status <> <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="Credit">
GROUP BY
  txt_web_name
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a conditional sum:

```
SELECT txt_web_name, SUM(mon_pay_amount) AS webTotal, AVG(mon_pay_amount) AS webAvg,
       sum(case when txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' then mon_pay_amount else 0 end
          ) as TotalNoCredit,
       avg(case when txt_pay_type <> 'Credit' then mon_pay_amount end
          ) as AvgNoCredit
FROM tbl_payment
     INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_orders ON (uid_pay_orderid = uid_orders)
     INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_websites ON (uid_order_webid = uid_websites)
WHERE dbo.tbl_payment.bit_pay_paid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_bit" value="yes">
      AND txt_pay_status <> <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="Credit">
GROUP BY txt_web_name
```

Notice for the sum, I default to 0, so no values in a month will result in $0.  For the average, I default to NULL, so the credit values do not get calculated in the  average.

Comment: Thank you, all of the solutions were correct, and worked well. I have marked Gordon Linoff as correct as answered first. And marked the rest up. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CASE` statement to decide whether to add or subtract a `mon_pay_amount`, something like

```
SELECT
    txt_web_name,
    SUM(CASE 
        WHEN txt_pay_type = 'credit' 
        THEN -1 * mon_pay_amount 
        ELSE mon_pay_amount END) AS webTotal,
...
```

Comment: Thank you, all of the solutions were correct, and worked well. I have marked Gordon Linoff as correct as answered first. And marked the rest up. Thank you –

Answer (score 1):

Not clear exactly what the columns are but something like this would work a champ:

```
SUM(CASE txt_pay_type = 'credit' 
    THEN mon_pay_amount 
    ELSE (-1*mon_pay_amount) END) AS webTotal,
```